# Macros or whatever else to zoom text in VS 2008 text editor

Tags: visual-studio-2008, macros

Macros or whatever else to zoom text in VS 2008 text editor.

Comment: The best solution to enable Ctrl + Scroll to zoom text

Answer (score 0):

I blogged about this awhile ago: [Most Important Macro for Presenters](http://www.brianschmitt.com/2009/08/intro-to-visual-studio-macros-and-most.html) of course 2010 has built-in features but this works for 2008

```
' Increases the font size used within the editor.
Public Sub IncreaseTextEditorFontSize()
   Dim textEditorFontsAndColors As Properties
   textEditorFontsAndColors = DTE.Properties("FontsAndColors", "TextEditor")
   textEditorFontsAndColors.Item("FontSize").Value += fontSizeIncrement
End Sub

' Decreases the font size used within the editor.
Public Sub DecreaseTextEditorFontSize()
   Dim textEditorFontsAndColors As Properties
   Dim fontSize As [Property]

   textEditorFontsAndColors = DTE.Properties("FontsAndColors", "TextEditor")
   fontSize = textEditorFontsAndColors.Item("FontSize")

   If fontSize.Value >= minimumSupportedEditorSize Then
       fontSize.Value -= fontSizeIncrement
   End If
End Sub
```